# GNU Readline- like history, for the latex terminal shell?

Tags: tex-core, keyboard, terminal-output

I find myself more than often willing to use the (pdf)latex shell, and `\typeout` commands there directly - unfortunately, there is one deal breaker: there is no command line history. I think that in Unix terminal emulators (or shells like `bash`? cannot really tell), this functionality is provided by GNU `readline`. So, on a `readline` enabled shell, I can press up and down arrow, and recall past commands, and easily re-execute them with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>; and I can also skip words with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + left or right arrow key.

Unfortunately, when I try those combos in my `pdflatex` shell, I get this:

```
$ pdflatex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\typeout{a}
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
a

*^[[A^[[D^[[C^[[1;5D^[[1;5C^[[1;5A^[[1;5B^C
```

... that is, I get escaped key sequences like `^[[A`, and obviously, there is no keyboard shell navigation.

So my question is: can `latex` in principle be built with `readline` support for keyboard shell interaction? I'd understand if distributions would not build it with such support, even if it exists (to reduce dependencies) -- I'm just interested if, in principle, there is an already existing "configure setting" to build latex with `readline` (at least on *nix systems).

Comment: Did you try     ``rlwrap pdflatex``?

Comment: Oh wow - thanks @phg , that seems to work perfectly! It offers all I wanted - and it will even jump to opening brace, once you've typed a closing brace, to indicate which nesting level you're closing, awesome `:)` ... Cheers!

Comment: Dont forget to customize your ``~/.inputrc``!

Comment: @phg, if only I learned this command years ago, to use rogue command line programs like Mathematica...  It should be an answer.

Comment: @phg do you mind turning your comment into an answer, to remove this item from the unanswered queue (and to add it to my favourites :o) ?

Comment: @erreka: I’d love to, I just can’t seem to get the captcha to
work in my browser. How nice of them to tell me I don’t pass the
robot filter only *after* I already
composed the answer! Unbelievable how much this site has
degenerated … Anyways, here’s my post: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/608858f78efac2133bf0
-- feel free to post it as your own for some free internet points. ``=)``

Answer (score 3):

Per @phg's suggestion, I'll post this answer on his behalf: if running a posix compliant system, try `rlwrap tex`; that indeed keeps record of keys typed on TeX's command line without linking it to `readline`.

Your `(pdf)latex` is very likely simply a symlink to the pdftex interpreter, which is actually what runs under the hood. Having that in mind, from [@phg's contribution](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/608858f78efac2133bf0):

> Linking readline would violate the core principles of Luatex and
>   Pdftex. (I don’t know about Xetex -- perhaps they don’t like the
>   license.) On the one hand it means introducing a runtime dependency,
>   on the other hand the library remains platform specific, regardless of
>   how widespread and popular it is. Not the best foundation for
>   extending a feature as controversial as the interactive mode!
>
> An interactive interpreter without readline is quite inconvenient,
>   though. Luckily, that usability gap can be closed quite easily by
>   installing the `rlwrap(1)` utility. It takes an existing, dumb
>   interpreter and transparently adds a readline layer over the input.
>   This does not affect the output except for what readline would do, e.
>   g. displaying the “insert mode” indicator (`show-mode-in-prompt`) --
>   so best avoid it in your scripts.

Comment: You should copy-and-paste the content of https://gist.github.com/anonymous/608858f78efac2133bf0 in your answer. It is much more detailed and interesting, I think. I did, but you overwrote my edition.

Comment: @Clément I know. I didn't figure out how to turn it into a comment, which was pretty to the point, actually. My apologies: I'll proceed as you suggest.

Comment: @phg fantastic utility. At last I can use `etex` in interactive mode and do computations with my favorite math engine using `\message` and access previous inputs simply with arrow keys...